# If 'if' condition is false, statements do not execute in chrome, but execute in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This is the plnkr of my scenario](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y2SaK7ry98haCE7lcfnW?p=preview). When I debug this code in chrome, statement in second 'if' is not executed. But when I debug it in Firefox, the statement in second 'if' is executed.

[image]

```
angular.module('optionsExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    debugger;
    if(true){
        $scope.name = 'Foo';
    }
      if(false){
        $scope.name = 'lol';
    }

  }]);
```

Firefox version: 35.0.1
Chrome version: 41.0.2272.101 m

Why does it happen?

**Update:**

Also tested in Firefox 36.0.4, Same problem.

Comment: I tested your scenario in Firefox versions 30, 33.1.1 and 36.0.4. They all only execute the first 'if', same as Chrome.

Comment: @crates_barrels I replicated the issue in Firefox 35.  Chrome 40 was ok...

Comment: It only looks like its executing it, the debugger is just highlighting that line before skipping it

Comment: @PatrickEvans I put a breakpoint on that line.  It hit it...

Comment: Looking around, it seems Firefox 35 may have javascript issues.  Trying to find something definite.

Comment: Bit more info.  First, [here's a screengrab](http://imgur.com/8OgHTPN) of it clearly on that line.  Secondly, if I breakpoint that line, then hit play after it reaches the `debugger;` statement, it doesn't hit it.  **However**, if I use F10 to step through the code, it goes into _both_ if blocks.  Looks like a wierd bug in the firefox developer tools.

Comment: @JamesThorpe It indeed highlights the line when stepping through the code, but it clearly does not execute the second 'if'. Firebug seems to be experiencing the same issue. Very strange to say the least.

Comment: @crates_barrels Agreed.  Firefox just "helpfully" updated itself to 36 on my machine - have [replicated the issue locally](http://imgur.com/ofSvSng) on a very simple page.  Debugger seems to go to that line (when using "Step Over", after reaching the `debugger;` statement), but as you say - it's not actually executed.

Comment: I've not found a specific bug for it, but there is [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1129813) and [this one](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1003554) amongst a [bunch of others](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?short_desc=step&resolution=---&query_format=advanced&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr&component=Developer%20Tools%3A%20Debugger) that show there are issues outstanding in the step/debugging code.

Comment: Just adding my bit in facing the same problem, in case someone will benefit from looking at other (my) [scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969908/cant-determine-why-an-else-if-statement-enters-a-condition-that-evaluates-to-fa?noredirect=1#comment63386432_37969908).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This maybe a bug or it may just be how they designed it. But this seems to do with how the debugger deals with if statement conditions it can readily evaluate, and the code styling used (K&R, Allman, 1TBS, etc)

[image: debugger screen]

Lines of code that can have breakpoints set to them are shaded green, and ones that cannot are shaded gray by the debugger.

Simply put the debugger does not highlight if statement lines (and maybe even other control statement lines) that it can readily tell have a true/false condition. When setting a breakpoint the breakpoint will be put on the next breakable line of code instead.

In the case of blocks that use 1TBS/OTBS or K&R style formatting the debugger will highlight the first breakable line within the if block instead of the actual if statement line. This gives the false impression that the code inside false condition if statements are going to be executed next.

In the case of blocks that use Allman style formatting the debugger will not highlight any part of the if statement or code block when stepping through. And if you try to put a code break on the if statement it will skip the entire block and put the breakpoint on the next breakable line.

When the if statements do not use conditions that the debugger can readily read as true/false the debugger acts as expected.

Demo to test

```js
debugger;
var one = true;
var two = false;

//Allman Style
if(one)
{
  console.log("Truth");   
}
if(two)
{
  console.log("false");   
}

if(true)
{
  console.log("Truth");   
}
if(false)
{
  console.log("false");   
}

//1TBS/OTBS Style
if(one){
   console.log("Truth");   
}
if(two){
   console.log("false");   
}
if(true){
   console.log("Truth");   
}
if(false){
   console.log("false");   
}
```

Comment: Nice.  In my opinion it's definitely a bug - it really shouldn't highlight a line of code that it's not actually going to execute - ie it should stay on the `if(false)` line.  They do seem to have a bunch of issues open in this area, so there may be movement on it in a few versions time