# Can't determine why an else if statement enters a condition that evaluates to false

Tags: javascript

Consider the following object o, and a function findEmpty that is supposed to print to the console properties which value is an empty array.

```
var o={
    "StudentInfo": [{
        "Name1": [{
            "100": {
                "a": "12"
            }
        }, {
            "101": {
                "a": "50"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "Name2": [{
            "102": {}
        }, {
            "103": {
                "b": "50"
            }
        }]
    }]
}

function findEmpty(obj)
{
    for (var p in obj)
    {
        debugger;
        var propValue = obj[p];
        var condition = propValue && typeof propValue === 'object' && !Array.isArray(propValue);
        if (Array.isArray(propValue) && propValue.length == 0) {
            console.log('Property ' + p + ' has an empty array.');
        }
        else if (condition) {
            findEmpty(propValue);
        }
    }
}
```

In debugging, the condition that the else if is to check renders false, but it keeps entering it. What is it that I am missing?

[image]

**Update**: during debugging, running an if/else in the console on the same boolean variable will execute the code for the false evaluation.

[image]

Comment: Using the code you've posted, along with `findEmpty(o)`, `condition` comes out as `false` and both `if` statements are skipped.  At least in Chrome 51.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/yLf0bjyt/ The alert inside the else if is never triggered. You'll have to show code that replicates the behavior you're describing.

Comment: @JamesThope, Thanks for trying to help, will try... once again. Am using firefox.

Comment: @Juhana: this is all I have, plus issuing a `findEmpty(o)` in the console.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue in Firefox or in Node.js.

Comment: Then neither of these conditions *should be true*. You have no code branch to descend into a *filled* array; and that seems to work as expected.

Comment: @deceze: sorry, do not get what you meant. For all others, after running `findEmpty(o)`, the 4th F10 is the one that enters this else if. Don't understand how.

Comment: Could be a problem with the Firefox debugger: [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232423/if-if-condition-is-false-statements-do-not-execute-in-chrome-but-execute-in). (Hmm... I see I also commented on that one now, I _thought_ this sounded familiar...!)

Comment: I mean the only thing in `o` is an *array of objects*. Which is not an *empty array* (`if`) nor an object (`else`), so this code should produce no output. And that's exactly what it does for everyone here.

Comment: @deceze: what you say is fine, and I'll be happy if I was facing the same results as everybody else - but the fact I am not is the very reason for the question. Could it be that JamesThorpe got it? Am following up his lead.

Comment: Is the debugger the only reason why you think the execution enters the else if block? If you put a console.log statement inside it, does it show up in the console?

Comment: @Juhana: absolutely right. I updated the question showing that evaluating the expression in the console works as expected. Yes, the question is why the behavior is different in the debugger.

Comment: This seems to be a quirk of the Firefox debugger: **I got the same behaviour as you** when stepping through the code, in that the debugger highlighted that line inside the `else if`. However, the debugger isn't actually executing that code, it seems that it just moves the highlight to whatever the last line in the function is not counting the ones with just brackets. So when I added a line of code *after* the `else if` the highlight moved straight to there. When I added extra lines inside the `else if` the highlight moved to the last of those lines. Weird, reproducible, but misleading.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's covered in that question I linked to further up - I can't vote to close as a dupe as I've already voted (and retracted) for a different reason.

Comment: @JamesThorpe - The code from that other question didn't seem to behave in quite the same way for me, but I'm happy to accept that it is basically the same issue - I don't have the patience to fool around with it any further now that I know the problem is only in how the debugger displays stuff, not in what actually executes.

Comment: @JamesThorpe , thanks for all the efforts. You were the one to give me answer.

Answer (score -5):

How can a propValue be an object and an array at the same time?

Shouldn't it be:

```
var condition = propValue && typeof propValue === 'array' && !Array.isArray(propValue);
```

Comment: `array` isn't a type. Arrays are objects. (Hence the existence of the `isArray` function)

Comment: Are you overlooking the `!`...?

Comment: why does the condition evaluate to false and the if entering it is my problem.